# Recover right ID element in React Firebase App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I try to update data in react firebase application. Everything work fine, i can recover the right data in a modal, and modify them.

But, when I set my data to firebase (with a function "updateContent), my entire collection of item is delete because I did not specify the exact path of the selected item. So, to do that, I need to recover the ID of the selected Item in my function. My problem: I manage to retrieve all the information of my element, but not its ID. I try many thing, console.log every function with ID item, every thing it's okay except for my modal and my function "updateContent" (while the other information of my element is displayed without any problem)

Can you give me a little help ? Thank you in advance.

This is my code for each item, when function to pass the data from my Hit Component to my modal Component (modal is for modify item data):

```
function handleClick (hit, onEdit) {

  onEdit({id: hit.objectID, marque: hit.marque, numero: hit.numero, reference: hit.reference, marquesuite: hit.marquesuite, cote: hit.cote})

}

const Hit = ({hit, onEdit}) =>

    <div className="item" id={hit.objectID}>
       <img src={hit.avatarURL} width={150} height={150}></img>
        <h1 className="marque">{hit.marque}</h1>
        <h3 className="numero">{hit.numero}</h3>
        <h4 className="reference">{hit.reference}</h4>
        <h4 className="marquesuite">{hit.marquesuite}</h4>
        <p className="cote">{hit.cote}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => handleClick(hit, onEdit) }>Modifier</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => removeToCatalogue(hit)}>Supprimer</button> 
    </div>

  const Content = ({ onEdit, }) => {

    const EnhancedHit = props =>
       <Hit onEdit={ onEdit } { ...props } />

    return (
      <div className="text-center">  
        <Hits hitComponent={ EnhancedHit } />
      </div>
    )    


  }
```

And now, this is my modal component:

```
  updateContent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const catalogue = {
      marque: this.state.marque,
      marquesuite: this.state.marquesuite,
      numero: this.state.numero,
      reference: this.state.reference,
      cote: this.state.cote,
      id: this.state.key,
    }


    console.log(catalogue)

    //firebase.database().ref(`catalogue`/).set(catalogue);


    };



  onOpenModal = (hit) => {
    this.setState({ open: true, id: hit.objectID, marque: hit.marque, numero: hit.numero, reference: hit.reference, marquesuite: hit.marquesuite, cote: hit.cote });
    console.log(hit.marque, hit.id)
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };


  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render (){
    const { open } = this.state;


        <h1 className="text-center">Catalogue de capsule</h1>



        <InstantSearch
            apiKey="xxx"
            appId="xxx"
            indexName="xxx>


            <SearchBox translations={{placeholder:'Rechercher une capsule'}} width="500 px"/>


            <Content onEdit={this.onOpenModal}/>  


                <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
                <form onSubmit={this.updateContent} key={this.state.objectID}>
                  <h2>Modification de la capsule :</h2>
                  <p>Marque de la capsule:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="marque" value={this.state.marque} onChange={this.handleChange}></input></p>
                  <p>Numéro de la capsule:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero" value={this.state.numero} onChange={this.handleChange}></input></p>
                  <p>Référence de la capsule:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="marquesuite" value={this.state.marquesuite} onChange={this.handleChange}></input></p>
                  <p>Référence de la capsule (suite):<input type="text" class="form-control" name="reference" value={this.state.reference}onChange={this.handleChange}></input></p>
                  <p>Cote de la capsule:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cote" value={this.state.cote}onChange={this.handleChange}></input></p>
                  <button className="btn btn-success">Mettre à jour</button>
                </form>

                </Modal>



          </InstantSearch>
```

Comment: Could you please isolate the part of your code that does not work. It would be very time consuming to go through all your code... I have doubts anyone is going to help you at this stage.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected my post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. It was just given the same name in id props like this:

```
onEdit({objectID: hit.objectID ...})

onOpenModal = (hit) => {
    this.setState({ open: true, objectID: hit.objectID, ... });
};
```